# The square of a number is even if and only if the number itself is even

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing

I wish to prove that square of a number is even if and only if the number itself is even. Let's call that number $a$, we need to prove that 
$$
a^2\text{ is even}\Leftrightarrow a\text{ is even}
$$

We need to prove two things:

1. **If $a$ is even, then $a^2$ is also even.**

I think that I can do this part. If $a$ is even, then we can write $a=2k$ where $k$ is some integer. Now
$$
a^2=(2k)^2=4k^2=2(2k^2)
$$
which shows that $a^2$ is also even.

2. **If $a^2$ is even, then $a$ is also even.**

I am having difficulty here. If $a^2$ is even, then I can write $a^2=2m$ . for some integer $m$ but taking square root gives $a=\sqrt{2m}$ which can be written as $a=2\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}$ but the problem is that will $\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}$ always end up as some integer? I do not think so!

Comment: The trick is to use the contrapositive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part 2, suppose that $a$ is not even. Then $a$ is of the form 
\begin{align*}
a = 2k + 1
\end{align*}
Thus, $a^2$ is of the form
\begin{align*}
a^2 = 4k^2 + 4k + 1
\end{align*}
Since $4k^2 + 4k$ is even, $4k^2 + 4k + 1$ must be odd. Thus $a^2$ is odd, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for the $2^{nd}$ part: by [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid's_lemma) if a prime divides a product, then it must divide (at least) one of the factors, so $2 \mid a^2 = a \cdot a \implies 2 \mid a\,$.

Answer (score 0):

Possible generalization is as follows :

Let $n$ be a positive integer et let $p$ be a prime number. Then $p\mid n$ if, and only if, $p\mid n^2$.

One way is obvious. The other one may be seen as a direct consequence of [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid's_lemma).